# Edge in IE mode automation is not working with IEDriverServer

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, microsoft-edge, selenium-iedriver, iedriverserver

I was trying to automate Edge in IE mode using selenium `IEDriverServer.exe`. When the code is executed, the browser window appears on the screen and remains stuck for sometime throwing a timeout exception.

On debugging the code, this timeout exception is thrown while initializing the `InternetExplorerDriver` object.

Please do let me know if anyone is facing same problem and any solution to it.

**Automation Approach**

Using the code sample available on Microsoft website. All the pre-requisites mentioned on Selenium website are met.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp

**Observation**

Same code, when executed after adding the application URL in the Trusted Sites, is working.

**System Configuration**

- Operating System: Win 11
- Edge browser: 111.0.1661.43
- IEDriver Version: 4.0.0.0, 4.3.0.0, 4.8.1.0

[Code Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4K5Xp.png)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you use `InternetExplorerOptions.AddAdditionalCapability` so I guess you use Selenium WebDriver 3. Selenium WebDriver 3 is deprecated now, and you need to upgrade to the latest version Selenium WebDriver 4.8.1. Besides, you need to place the IEDriver in your PATH.

I test with Selenium WebDriver 4.8.1, IEDriver 4.8.1.0, Edge version 111.0.1661.44 on Win 11 with the [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/ie-mode?tabs=c-sharp#the-complete-sample), it works well. You can have a try.

Comment: It didn't work. I have shared more details over MS forum.